# Carbon returning wrong timezone offset for America/Sao_Paulo

Tags: laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I am using Carbon dates in my Laravel 8 project using PHP 7.
I recently came across a strange bug that occurring only on my production server and failed to execute locally.

I am sending an invite for the time set to timezone 'America/Sao_Paulo' which currently is operating over offset (-03:00), However, when I receive the email the timezone is rendered as (-02:00) and hence my conversion is all disturbed by one hour difference.

I even tried hardcoding it like below and the value dumped on production sometimes gives (-02:00) and other times the correct value which is (-03:00).

```php
$date = Carbon::now(tz: 'America/Sao_paolo')->getOffsetString();
dd($date);
```

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

in the AppServiceProvider.php you can add a little script for the whole Laravel app , please check

```
public function boot()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
}
```